# Flutter: Get json fixed data and ordered-by alphabetically

Tags: json, api, sorting, flutter, where-clause

I get data from a [json API](https://boimarket.abirahsan.com/public/api/v1/books). And want to show my app which data's category is equal to 1. I could have done this by call ***category-1 url link*** but I need all data by link at a time and then divided into many parts.

I am using `if(mydata[index].category==1)`then return. But I think it's a wrong way to divide it. It's show me wrong output.

And I want to also sorting this data by alphabetically.

Here is my code-

```
import 'package:boimarket/booksdescription.dart';
import 'package:boimarket/model/model.dart';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:draggable_scrollbar/draggable_scrollbar.dart';

class StoryBooksCategory extends StatefulWidget {
  final ScrollController controller;
  final List<Book> storybooks;
  StoryBooksCategory({Key key, @required this.controller, this.storybooks})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  _StoryBooksCategoryState createState() => _StoryBooksCategoryState();
}

class _StoryBooksCategoryState extends State<StoryBooksCategory> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var _height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    var _width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    final Color _whiteCream = Color.fromRGBO(250, 245, 228, 1);
    final Color _darkBlue = Color.fromRGBO(0, 68, 69, 1);
    return Align(
      alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
      child: Container(
        width: _width / 1.1,
        child: FutureBuilder(
          future: fetchBooks(),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (!snapshot.hasData) {
              return Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  LinearProgressIndicator(
                    backgroundColor: _whiteCream,
                  ),
                  Text("Loading"),
                ],
              );
            } else if (snapshot.hasData) {
              var mydata = snapshot.data;
              return DraggableScrollbar.rrect(
                controller: widget.controller,
                backgroundColor: _darkBlue,
                child: ListView.builder(
                  controller: widget.controller,
                  scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                  itemCount: mydata.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    if (mydata[index].category == 1)
                      return GestureDetector(
                        onTap: () {
                          Route route = MaterialPageRoute(
                            builder: (context) =>
                                BookDescription(storyBooksValue: mydata[index]),
                          );
                          Navigator.push(context, route);
                        },
                        child: Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                              left: 10.0, right: 10.0, top: 20.0),
                          child: Container(
                            width: _width / 1.1,
                            height: _height / 4,
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                color: _whiteCream,
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                                  Radius.circular(5.0),
                                ),
                                boxShadow: [
                                  BoxShadow(
                                    color: Colors.black26,
                                    blurRadius: 2,
                                    spreadRadius: 2,
                                    offset: Offset(2.0, 2.0),
                                  )
                                ]),
                            child: Row(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                              children: <Widget>[
                                Flexible(
                                  flex: 4,
                                  child: Padding(
                                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                                    child: Card(
                                      elevation: 10.0,
                                      child: ClipRRect(
                                        borderRadius:
                                            BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
                                        child: FadeInImage.assetNetwork(
                                          fadeOutCurve: Curves.easeInCubic,
                                          placeholder:
                                              'assets/images/bookshelf.jpg',
                                          image: mydata[index].imgUrl == null
                                              ? 'assets/images/bookshelf.jpg'
                                              : mydata[index].imgUrl,
                                          fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                                Flexible(
                                  flex: 6,
                                  child: Column(
                                    crossAxisAlignment:
                                        CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                    children: <Widget>[
                                      Row(
                                        children: <Widget>[
                                          Text(
                                            "বইয়ের নামঃ ",
                                            style: TextStyle(
                                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                                          ),
                                          Flexible(
                                            child: Text(
                                              "${mydata[index].name}",
                                              overflow: TextOverflow.fade,
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                        ],
                                      ),
                                      Row(
                                        children: <Widget>[
                                          Text(
                                            "লেখকঃ ",
                                            style: TextStyle(
                                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                                          ),
                                          Flexible(
                                            child: Text(
                                              "${mydata[index].author}",
                                              overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                        ],
                                      ),
                                      Row(
                                        children: <Widget>[
                                          Text(
                                            "বইয়ের ধরণঃ ",
                                            style: TextStyle(
                                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                                          ),
                                          Flexible(
                                            child: Text(
                                              "${mydata[index].genreClass}",
                                              overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                        ],
                                      ),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      );
                  },
                ),
              );
            } else {
              return Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Icon(Icons.error_outline),
                  Text("Somthing Went to wrong"),
                ],
              );
            }
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a where clause to filter out the books you want - for example:

```
var books = await fetchBooks();
var cat1books = books.where((b) => b.category == 1).toList();
```

You might use that here:

```
var mydata = snapshot.data.where((b) => b.category == 1).toList();
mydata.sort((a, b) => a.name.compareTo(b.name));
```

Comment: Category is Ok but how to sorting it by  alphabetically. 



     var storybooks = snapshot.data.where((b) => b.category == 1).toList();
     var mydata = storybooks.sort((a, b) => a.name.compareTo(b.name));



It's not working.

Comment: `sort` returns `null` - so you've made `mydata` null! Instead use: `storybooks.sort(...);` and then `var mydata = storybooks;`