# Flutter cache problem: The operator '[]' isn't defined for the type 'Book'

Tags: flutter, caching

I am getting data from a json API and want to save  my data as a cache file to phone. But I am facing a problem to implementation. It's show me a error ( The operator '[]' isn't defined for the type 'Book' )

Here is my code :

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
    
final String _baseUrl =
    "https://boimarket.abirahsan.com/api/v1/categories/1/books";
Future<List<Book>> fetchBooks() async {
  String fileName = 'booksdata.json';
  var dir = await getTemporaryDirectory();
  File file = File(dir.path + "/" + fileName);
  if (file.existsSync()) {
    var jsonData = file.readAsStringSync();
    Book response =json.decode(jsonData);
    return response['data'].map<Book>((b) => Book.fromJson(b)).toList();
  } else {
    var response = await http.get(_baseUrl);
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      var jsonResponse = response.body;
      var decoded = json.decode(jsonResponse);
      file.writeAsStringSync(jsonResponse, flush: true, mode: FileMode.write);
      return decoded['data'].map<Book>((b) => Book.fromJson(b)).toList(); //**Here is the problem to implementation ['data']**
    } else {
      throw Exception('Failed to load Book');
    }
  }
}

class Book {
  final String name;
  final String author;
  final String imgUrl;
  final String pdf;
  final String html;
  final String description;
  final int category;

  Book({
    this.name,
    this.author,
    this.imgUrl,
    this.description,
    this.html,
    this.pdf,
    this.category,
  });

  factory Book.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Book(
      name: json['name'],
      imgUrl: json['image'],
      pdf: json['pdf'],
      html: json['html'],
      description: json['description'],
      author: json['author'],
      category: json['category'],
    );
  }
}
```

Actually where is the problem and How can I fix this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is actually here:

```
Book response =json.decode(jsonData);
return response['data'].map<Book>((b) => Book.fromJson(b)).toList();
```

`response` is not a `Book`. Change `Book response` to `var response`. (Or, even better, `var decoded`.)

Comment: Do you solved my another problem please?
https://stackoverflow.com/q/63281736/12902996

Answer (score 1):

The error lies here:

```
Book response =json.decode(jsonData);
```

The `Book` class does not have any [] operator. Try changing the type to `var` instead